# How to store changes in SQL database?

Tags: sql

I am making an app, that uses Instagram data to create some kind of rating of user profiles and their posts. My app periodically add new like/comment count with timestamp for stored posts in db and check profiles for new posts to add them in database.

Database schema for posts updates table:

```
id, post_id, user_id, likes_count, comments_count, timestamp
```

So, the question is: is there more efficient way to store count (likes/comments) updates?

Comment: What have you done so far? Why is the current solution not efficient?

Comment: Why storing counts anyway? I guess you have a table to hold the comments and a table to hold the likes, so why do you need to store values that can be queried from these tables?

Comment: I use this data in following ways: 1) overall count for user profile likes and comments 2) comparing (1) for some periods of time (used for profile ranking) 3) finding out trendy posts. I think current solution is not perfect and might create some excess and unnecessary data.

Comment: I don't have tables for comments and likes and they aren't needed to make ranking (app actually doesn't care about content of comments and which exact user pressed like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with what you have done. It is efficient just set default values of zero for the likes_count and comments_count fields others not null.